# Islamic View of Veganism

Tags: halal-haram, animals, health

Is it haram to be a vegan? I'm currently a vegetarian, simply because I don't enjoy meat as much as I did before. I don't think that we really need meat to survive, and all this mass production is just horrible! For the animals and for our body, those animals are mostly sick because of their poorly living in a way too small cage and they basically transfer their illness to us, it's just horrible. Same with the egg and dairy industry. I would enjoy those products if people weren't so cruel and kept the animals in a good way. In the dairy industry as an example they get the cow pregnant and once the cow gives birth her baby is taken away from her just to get killed. I just hate how humans use animals as a material; and like I said, I just strongly disapprove of the mass production, I want my body to be healthy and I don't think that stuffing my body with poison will do. Is my thinking wrong? And would it be okay to be vegan?

Answer (score 0):

Well of course, I think most people would agree with you however(as in how animals are treated in the current day), however, you have to remember that **Halal Organic** meats are in-fact available where the welfare and well being of the animal is a high priority. Also consider the fact that the requirements for the meat to be Halal is a must and therefore, there is an assurance that the animal is healthy before death.

I really do recommend you watch this video, it quite informative and will pretty much answer your question: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WZaW_P-szCU